# Taylor approximation of Gaussian pdf around the origin

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi(x)$ be the standard Gaussian pdf, i.e. $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$. Can a constant $K$ be found such that $$|\phi(x+y)-\phi(x)-\phi(y)+\phi(0)|\leq K|xy|$$ for all $|x|,|y|\leq 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to find a constant $C$ such that
$$\left|e^{-(x+y)^2/2}-e^{-x^2/2}-e^{-y^2/2}+1\right|\leq C\,|xy| $$
for any $|x|,|y|\leq 1$. Since, by setting $A=e^{-x^2/2},B=e^{-y^2/2}$:
$$ AB e^{-xy}-A-B+1 = (A-1)(B-1)+AB(e^{-xy}-1) $$
it follows that:
$$\left|e^{-(x+y)^2/2}-e^{-x^2/2}-e^{-y^2/2}+1\right|\leq \left((e^{-1/2}-1)^2+(e-1)\right)|xy|\tag{1}$$
since for any $z\in[-1,1]$ we have:
$$e^{-z^2}\leq 1,\quad \left|\frac{e^{-z^2/2}-1}{z}\right|\leq(e^{-1/2}-1),\quad \left|\frac{e^{-z}-1}{z}\right|\leq e-1,$$
so the triangle inequality simply gives:
$$\left|\phi(x+y)-\phi(x)-\phi(y)+1\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{e}+e-\frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}\right)|xy|\tag{2}$$
and the initial inequality holds with $K=0.74725876555468\ldots$ or just with $K=\frac{3}{4}.$

---

However, the optimal constant seems to be just $K=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, since the graphics of $g(x,y)=\frac{\phi(x+y)-\phi(x)-\phi(y)+\phi(0)}{xy}$ is very well-behaved on $[-1,1]^2$:

$\hspace1in$[image]